# loading only a specific element properly in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

i am trying to load only a specific element in my webview webpage ('contentbody').
but i dont know how to modify my code to load that only. i can block elements in my webview by using this simple javascript.

```
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
        // Removes element which id = 'mastHead'
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                + "(elem = document.getElementById('smsform')).parentNode.removeChild(elem); "
                + "})()");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An option might be to use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org), to load the HTML page from the website, extract the desired portion of the HTML, and then load just that into your WebView. A small example of how it could be done:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://example.com/", doc.select(".contentbody").first().outerHtml(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

With this, you use Jsoup to extract the first item with `contentbody` class from the HTML, and then directly load it into your WebView.